# Not_Fitted_Error : This LabelEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

`I am new to Ml_Modelling`
`I am working on a solution to create a model with three columns nature_of_business , industry, products.`

| nature_of_business | industry | products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Manufacturer | capitalgoods | product1 |
| Services | Mining | product2 |
| Other | capitalgoods | product3 |
| Manufacturer | commercialservices | product4 |

`Now, with the label encoder I'm encoding the entire Data Frame.`

```
df = df.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

`After this i have splitted the data into  test and test and created the model`.

`Now, I'm trying to predict the Product using the model for a new Dataframe. I'm using the same Label encoder as used earlier.`

```
df_Predict = pd.DataFrame({
'Industry_nature_of_business': ['Manufacturer'], 
'Industry_Category': ['Capital Goods']})
 df_encoded_Predict = df_Predict.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
 predictions_train = knc.predict(df_encoded_Predict)
 print(LabelEncoder().inverse_transform(predictions_train))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
encoder=LabelEncoder()
df_encoded_Predict = df_Predict.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
predictions_train = knc.predict(df_encoded_Predict)
print(LabelEncoder().inverse_transform(predictions_train))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thank you for your contribution. On order to improve your answer, can you explain what it does and how it works?